# How to print code from GitHub.com with its syntax-highlighting?

Tags: printing, syntax-highlighting, github

How can one print just the syntax highlighted source code from a GitHub source code page ([e.g.](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/.issue-guidelines.js))?  I've tried it with a few browsers (Safari, Firefox, both running on OS X) but I have not succeeded in getting the syntax highlighting.  (The rest of the printout doesn't look too great either; it includes much other stuff that is both uninteresting and ugly-looking.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would pulling the code, opening it up in Vim and printing it from there with [Github colorscheme](https://github.com/endel/vim-github-colorscheme) be considered an option?

Answer (score -1):

Use a browser (firefox) plugin to either edit the page before printing or to make a "long" screenshot and print that.

Two examples:

http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2010/09/24/print-edit-for-firefox-lets-you-easily-format-web-pages-for-prin/
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/fireshot/?src=search

Answer (score -1):

I've just created a [style](http://stylebot.me/styles/15540) for the stylebot extension, which will load it into your browser when you visit github.

The code just hide everything that is not code.
It should work for both code and wiki pages.